# How to Remove substring from string

Tags: java

I wan't to remove Y from X and this compiles, however when I run it in my main method I get an error saying out of bounds. I am unsure what is wrong. any help would be appreciated.

```
public static String filter(String X, String Y) {
    String i = X;
    if ((X != null) && (X.length() >0) && (Y != null) &&Y.length() >0 && (i !=null)){
        int z = X.indexOf(Y);
        i = X.substring(0, z) +X.substring(z + Y.length());
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: most probably  `indexOf` is giving you `-1` because `y` is not present in `x`

Answer (score 1):

As @singhakash already pointed out that

```
int z = X.indexOf(Y); --> this is returning -1
```

So

```
X.substring(0, z)
```

become

```
X.substring(0, -1)
```

causing OutOfBounds Exception

P.S. 
Why have you complicated it so much !! Instead  you can use `String#replace` or `String#replaceAll`

```
String X="StackOverflow";
String Y="flow";
X=X.replaceAll(Y,"");
System.out.println(X);
```

Output

```
StackOver
```

[**Demo1**](http://ideone.com/t78fLy)- if y is not present in x you get index out of bound

[**Demo2**](http://ideone.com/hZsccW)- if y is present in x you will get correct output

Comment: I need to do it without using replace. I know how much easier it would be.

Comment: then probably you should check that , Y exists or not in X ...!!

Answer (score 1):

Use [replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method

```
public static String filter(String X, String Y) {
    return X.replaceAll(Y,"");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this will work for you :

```
if((x !=null && y !=null) && x.contains(y)) {
   System.out.println(x.replaceAll(y, ""));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1` occurs when the length of string X is less than string Y because of this `X.substring(z + Y.length())`

Have a additional check for "X.length() > Y.length()" and it should work fine.

Comment: I added the extra check and it still errors out, do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you please share the sample input that is used for your testing. Below   is the code snippet. `public static String filter(String X, String Y) {
        String i = X;
    if ((X != null) && (X.length() >0) && (Y != null) &&Y.length() >0 && (i !=null) && (X.length() > Y.length())) {
        int z = X.indexOf(Y);
        i = X.substring(0, z) +X.substring(z + Y.length());
    }
   return i;
 }`

Answer (score 0):

**If You want to remove all occurrence of Y in X use the following code.**

```
public static String filter(String X, String Y) {
if ((X != null) && (X.length() >0) && (Y != null) &&Y.length() >0) {
while(X.contains(Y)){
int z = X.indexOf(Y);
X = X.substring(0, z) +X.substring(z + Y.length());
}}
return X;
```

also if X does not contain Y then
`int z = X.indexOf(Y);` --> this is returning -1
`X.substring(0, z)` ie `X.substring(0, -1)`-->causing **OutOfBounds Exception**

It is better to use `X=X.replaceAll(Y,"");`

Answer (score -1):

You can use this:

```
String subString = testString.subString(firstIndex, secondIndex);
```

and you can get the index by this:

```
int index = testString.indexOf(String);
```

Comment: OP is already using both of the methods you suggested, so what's your point?

Comment: I can run this from method call but as soon as i try my main method it errors out.

Comment: You can check if Y is in X by doing this: X.contains(Y);